# Combine List Validation Checks

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have the following List Validations working independently but I'm struggling to combine them into one validation.

```
=IF(AND(devValidation="Yes",devMethod="Post"),IF(devOverride<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
=IF(devLocked="Yes",FALSE)
```

When I tried adding an OR to the statement the devLocked was never validated.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, if you set three conditions in list validation, you don't need to combine them together. Your three conditions can't be combined as well.